# preg_match_all expression

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to extract src value from image tag using prag_match with perl pattern. I don't know where I'm making wrong but, I'm getting unwanted part as well. Here's how my pattern look like -

```
preg_match_all('#src="http.+"#',$imagetag,$temp);

$imagetag = "<img src="http://....." alt="build4.jpg" title="build4.jpg" width="320" height="240" />"
```

Instead of returning src="..." part, I'm getting the whole attributes - src=".." alt=".." title=".." width=".." height="..";something wrong with my patten. I would appreciate much if anyone can point out the mistake.

Comment: Erm, I don't think that's Perl... that looks more like PHP. With Perl-compatible regex.

Comment: Please consider using a proper DOM parser rather than a regexp based scraper to parse HTML.

Comment: @Bolt : Sorry my bad. It is php with perl compatible regex. @Noufal:would it make my script slower because of overhead that I need to create object and pass the tag?Cuz I only need to work on 4 tags at most.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make your pattern non-greedy by using `.+?` in place of `.+` as:

```
preg_match_all('#src="http.+?"#',$imagetag,$temp);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot;it works. If you don't mind me asking, how does adding ? change the whole result? I mean, I thought enclosing .+ inside quotation mark would restrict return result to those with src="alphanumeric/symbol";seems to me it considers closing quotation mark of the last attribute as a match of quotation mark from my pattern and consider all the rest of attributes as a match for pattern .+.